# Prevention of unauthorized downloads. Android and ios adverts

Tags: android, ios, download, unauthorized

Too many advertisements to keep track of.
Upon occasion, an unauthorized download will slip through the cracks of these billions of advertisements that are
displayed or even hidden. I have noticed that some adverts will automatically force a download that can be stopped
 ' if you see it as it is happening. '
Is there a script we can use prevent an automatic download while a game is being played?
( in android and ios )

Comment: Trusted sources of advertisement have their own way to manage that. To use them you will have to accept their rules. Ex Admob

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for. I have been using adf.ly. I have tried a plethora of others in conjunction and noticing that they do not all carry the same stats. Bidvertiser, Admob, and a slue of others will rip you off. It seems they all want you to display ads, but they do not want to pay you. Adfly pays well, but some of ads have automatic downloads or redirected downloads. so the question still remains. Is there a script we can use prevent an automatic downloads?